# Boolean algebra helpers for composition of RxJS Observables

Tags: rxjs, boolean-operations

How can I avoid writing crazy `combineLatest` statements for calculation of simple boolean logic expressions?

eg. this simple expression barely even fits in the stackoverflow code control, and if you accidentally reorder the parameters you'll have a really hard time debugging!

```
this.showPlayButton = combineLatest(this.playPending, this.isReady, this.showOverlay)
  .pipe(
   map(([playPending, isReady, showOverlay]) => isReady && !playPending && showOverlay),
   distinctUntilChanged();
```

Answer (score 5):

Ok so I've been quite surprised that I couldn't find an existing library for this, so I've started collecting together a few helper observable creation functions.

#### `Observable<boolean>` helpers

These are the 'purest' helpers, take in and also output `Observable<boolean>`. I've added `distinctUntilChanged()` to each, which prevents multiple unnecessary emissions. This is a very inert operator without the more complex consequences of `share` or `shareReplay(1)` - but it's important to be aware it has been applied.

```
export const allTrue = (...observables: Array<ObservableInput<boolean>> ) => combineLatest(observables).pipe(map(values => values.every(v => v == true) ), distinctUntilChanged());
export const allFalse = (...observables: Array<ObservableInput<boolean>> ) => combineLatest(observables).pipe(map(values => values.every(v => v == false) ), distinctUntilChanged());
export const anyTrue = (...observables: Array<ObservableInput<boolean>> ) => combineLatest(observables).pipe(map(values => values.find(v => v == true) != undefined ), distinctUntilChanged());
export const anyFalse = (...observables: Array<ObservableInput<boolean>> ) => combineLatest(observables).pipe(map(values => values.find(v => v == false) != undefined), distinctUntilChanged());

export const not = (observable: Observable<boolean> ) => observable.pipe(map(value => !value), distinctUntilChanged());
```

#### Boolean converters for truthy / falsey

Some other 'helpers' in the same category, such as `ifTruthy` or `ifFalsy` are intended to be used with the above helpers (since they require true boolean values). These currently use `!=` as opposed to `!==`, so `isDefined(of(null))` and `isDefined(of(undefined))` both product a `true` Observable. Also `isEqual` won't be a deep comparison.

```
 export const isTruthy = <T>(observable: Observable<T>) => observable.pipe(map(obsValue => !!obsValue), distinctUntilChanged());
 export const isFalsey = <T>(observable: Observable<T>) => observable.pipe(map(obsValue => !obsValue), distinctUntilChanged());

 export const isDefined = <T>(observable: Observable<T>) => observable.pipe(map(obsValue => obsValue != undefined), distinctUntilChanged());
 export const isEqual = <T>(observable: Observable<T>, value: T) => observable.pipe(map(obsValue => obsValue == value), distinctUntilChanged());
 export const notEqual = <T>(observable: Observable<T>, value: T) => observable.pipe(map(obsValue => obsValue != value), distinctUntilChanged());
```

There's also a third category such as `iff` which is equivalent to SQL Server's  [`iff`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-iif-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) statment. The output of these is either `A` or `B` (the type of whatever your parameters are). This is like a very simple if statement.

```
export const iff = <A, B>(ifObs: Observable<boolean>, trueValue: A, falseValue: B) => ifObs.pipe(map(value => value ? trueValue : falseValue));
```

#### Composition

With RxJS it's super easy to compose them together and create very readable combinations. I often use these in Angular components for UI specific properties, and it's much easier to debug. These below are real code examples and should be pretty self explanatory.

```
loading$ = not(this.loaded$);
hasSelectedOrder$ = isTruthy(orderId$);  // Note: this wouldn't work for something zero
hasSelectedOrder$ = isDefined(orderId$);  // uses != undefined 

layout$ = iff(deviceType.isDesktop$, 'horizontal', 'vertical');
isMobileOrTablet$: anyTrue(this.isMobile$, this.isTablet);
isTabletOrDesktop$: anyTrue(this.isTablet, this.isDesktop$);

isBusy$ = anyTrue(this.hasBusyTask$, this.busyService.isBusy$);

// very useful for UI (using async pipe)
isAddNewCreditCardSelected$ = isEqual(selectedPaymentMoniker$, 'NEW');
showSavedPayments$ = allTrue(showAvailablePaymentMethods$, hasVault$, not(isAddNewCreditCardSelected$));
showAddCreditCardButton$ = allTrue(showPaymentButtons$, not(showAddCreditCardPanel$), not(showVault$))
showDefaultFooter$ = allTrue(not(this.isWebapp$), this.showDefaultFooter$);
showBusyIndicator$ = allTrue(not(this.pageService.handlesBusyIndicator$), this.busyService.isBusy$) ;
```

And as for the original question, it simply becomes this:

```
this.showPlayButton$ = allTrue(this.isReady$, not(this.playPending$), this.showOverlay$)
```

I will add to this list as I come up with new ones. These have covered most situations I've come across so far. This could certainly be made into a library, but I'm not able to formalize this right now to be able to do that. If something already exists would love to compare :-)

Comment: Nice. Some consideration was given to making the RxJS APIs for `map`, `filter` and `scan` similar to those of `Array`. I'd be inclined to go with `every` and `some` instead of `all` and `any` because that's what's used with `Array`.

Comment: @cartant thanks :) definitely just a start but I’m finding these invaluable for writing cleaner code, especially when I have a series of booleans to prepare for UI. You could certainly take this in many directions and I’d love to see someone able to formalize them and consider further options. I’ll probably leave my own version with these names (or small changes) since one goal was to make the code read as close to English as I could - and usually without pipe(). The distinct check was also very deliberate for my use-case but it’s debatable whether you’d want that in a library.